# TransactionSignatureVerificationFailure when Sending Solana Swap Transaction

Tags: python, api, sol, jupiter

I'm attempting to execute a swap transaction on the Solana network using Python and the Solana API. However, I'm encountering an error related to TransactionSignatureVerificationFailure during the transaction process.
After successfully obtaining a swap instruction and signing the transaction with my private key, I encounter the following error when attempting to send the transaction:
solana.rpc.core.RPCException: RpcCustomErrorFieldless.TransactionSignatureVerificationFailure

````
import requests
from solana.rpc.api import Client 
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.rpc.api import Client
import base64                                      
import solders
import httpx
http_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/")
pv_key =  "pvkey"
wallet = Keypair.from_base58_string(pv_key)

print(wallet.pubkey())
r = requests.get('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v&amount=1000000&slippageBps=1')

if r.status_code == 200:
            quote_response = r.json()
            response = requests.post('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', json={
                "quoteResponse": quote_response,
                "userPublicKey": str(wallet.pubkey()),  # Corrected attribute name
                "wrapAndUnwrapSol": True
            })

if response.status_code == 200:
            swap_instruction = response.json()["swapTransaction"]

            raw_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))

            message_to_sign = bytes(raw_tx.message)
            signature = wallet.sign_message(message_to_sign)

            signed_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])
            encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(signed_tx)).decode('utf-8')
            headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            data = {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 1,
                "method": "sendTransaction",
                "params": [
                    encoded_tx,
                    {
                        "skipPreflight": True,
                        "preflightCommitment": "finalized",
                        "encoding": "base64",
                        "maxRetries": None,
                        "minContextSlot": None
                    }
                ]
            }
            txid = http_client.send_transaction(signed_tx)
            print(txid.json())
else : 
            print("error")```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify this a bit. There are a few too many conversions going on, and likely something wrong is getting passed in. Assuming that the transaction is actually in base64, try signing and sending the transaction directly, ie:

```
            swap_tx = response.json()["swapTransaction"]
            tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_tx))
            txid = http_client.send_transaction(tx, wallet)
```