# "Encountering ValueError: *signers args are not used when sending VersionedTransaction in Solana Python Library"

Tags: transactions, python, versionedtransactions, solana-py, jupiter

I'm currently working on integrating Solana functionality into my Python application using the Solana Python library. During the process of sending a transaction, I encountered a ValueError with the message "*signers args are not used when sending VersionedTransaction."

```
import solana 
import requests
from solana.rpc.api import Client 
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction 
from solana.transaction import Transaction , Message,Instruction
from solders.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.rpc.api import Client
import base64                                      
import solders
import httpx
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
http_client = Client("https://tame-solemn-layer.solana-mainnet.quiknode.pro/6f2546981f01160bfe3685e910532b69c7409047/")
pv_key =  "mypv"
wallet = Keypair.from_base58_string(pv_key)

print(wallet.pubkey())
r = requests.get('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote?inputMint=So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112&outputMint=EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v&amount=1000000&slippageBps=1')

if r.status_code == 200:
    quote_response = r.json()
    
    # Get recent blockhash
    recent_blockhash = http_client.get_latest_blockhash()

    if recent_blockhash:
        # Decode swap instruction
        response = requests.post('https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap', json={
            "quoteResponse": quote_response,
            "userPublicKey": str(wallet.pubkey()),  # Corrected attribute name
            "wrapAndUnwrapSol": True
        })
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            swap_instruction = response.json()["swapTransaction"]
            raw_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))

            # Convert message to bytes
            message_to_sign = solders.message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message)

            # Sign message
            signature = wallet.sign_message(message_to_sign)
            
            # Populate signed transaction
            signed_tx = solders.transaction.VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])

            encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(signed_tx)).decode('utf-8')
            headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            data = {
                "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                "id": 1,
                "method": "sendTransaction",
                "params": [
                    encoded_tx,
                    {
                        "skipPreflight": True,
                        "preflightCommitment": "finalized",
                        "encoding": "base64",
                        "maxRetries": None,
                        "minContextSlot": None
                    }
                ]
            }   
            opts = TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, skip_preflight=True, max_retries=3)
            print(signed_tx)
            txid = http_client.send_transaction(signed_tx,opts)
            print(txid)
        else : 
            print("error")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TransactionSignatureVerificationFailure when Sending Solana Swap Transaction](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/10043/transactionsignatureverificationfailure-when-sending-solana-swap-transaction)